# What is the equivalent of the Windows “Startup Folder” In Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mac, operating-systems

In Windows OS there is a “Startup Folder.”

We can simply create a shortcut to the folder.

Then, after the next computer reboot, the application or file will be executed automatically.

How to do it in the Mac OS?

Where is that folder?

How to create shortcut of a file to it?

Answer (score 3):

System Preferences > Users & Groups > your account > Login Items

are all the items that are automatically run as you log in to your account.

You can click and hold on an icon in the Dock and select

Options > Open at Login

from the menu that pops up and it will be added to the list in System Preferences.

Source: [My Question On Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20150517094451AA4A0dJ)

Answer (score 2):

in your autostart file  (Users & Groups menu  -- login items  (is where to find it)  add / remove things as you see fit   also  there is http://www.apple.stackexchange.com   for future  Apple  centric questions FYI

Comment: As an aside: Apple questions are very welcome here as well. (I, for one, rarely ever visit Ask Different.)

Comment: Same here was merely  a FYI  not a redirect -- 1000 apologizes  if seemed as such